# Laravel 8 Does Not Show Data From DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I have made a resource Controller to return some results from MySQL table so `index()` method of this Controller holds:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

At at `index.blade.php` I added this:

```
@section('content')
   <h1>Posts</h1>
   @if(count($posts)>1)
      @foreach($posts as $post)
         <div class="well">
            <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
         </div>
      @endforeach
   @endif
@endsection
```

So as you can see, it look fine but the problem is it does not show me any output! I mean no results and no errors at all.

Here is also my table info:

[image: capture]

However, on PHPStorm editor, the line `return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);` has a notice sign which is saying:

> Extend retrun type from
> `\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\View\View`

But I don't what does it mean?

So if you know how to solve this problem, please let me know, I would really appreciate any idea from you guys.

Comment: How many posts do you have in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like the issue here is a simple logic issue. On the line where you check for the count of the `$posts` variable using `@if(count($posts)>1)`, the if condition would fail if you have only one post in your database. This is because `1 is not greater than 1`. You wouldn't see anything in your view even though there is one post in your database. To fix the issue, modify your code to this:

```php
@if(count($posts) > 0)
```

OR

```php
@if(count($posts) >= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First , You should check the $posts variable has data or not by using dd($posts) or return $posts in controller itself. If dd or return has data then check the same in blade file.

Rather then using @if(count($posts) > 0) You should use @if(isset($posts)).